# How to distribute elements evenly side by side?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make team profiles for the website, what I want is it to 3 profiles to display horizontally evenly.

```
<div>
    <span>
        <img>
        <span></span>
    </span>
    <span>
        <img>
        <span></span>
    </span>
    <span>
        <img>
        <span></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

right now output is:

```
<img><span><img><span><img><span>
```

output expected:

```
<img>   <img>   <img>
<span>  <span>  <span>
```

Comment: Please show your actual code, **what you have tried** instead of pseudo code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Where is your CSS? You might want to consider using `div`s for the outer `spans`. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You could use flex or grid. Something like this:

```
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

div > span > * { //this is to move the spans below the imgs
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put every profile in an inline div and make span a block element, like

```css
img{width:70px;}
span{display:block}
.inline{display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="inline">
    <span>
        <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png">
        <span>User</span>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="inline">
    <span>
        <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png">
        <span>User</span>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="inline">
    <span>
        <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png">
        <span>User</span>
    </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Every div wraps the image and the user and itself being inline, adds the other div in line.